# \printbibliography Undefined Control Sequence error in Documentclass letter

Tags: biblatex, letters

Attempting to compile the minimal working example below with either PDFLaTeX or XeLaTeX results in the compiler finishing with exit code 1 and reporting an `undefined control sequence` for whatever happens to follow \printbibliography, which is a blank line in the example code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter} % 12pt font size, 10pt and 11pt are also possible

\usepackage{geometry} % Required for adjusting page dimensions

\geometry{
    paper=letterpaper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    top=1.00in, % Top margin
    bottom=1.00in, % Bottom margin
    left=1.00in, % Left margin
    right=1.00in, % Right margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{DummyBibliography.bib}
@book{sandarsEpicGilgamesh1977,
  title = {The Epic of {{Gilgamesh}}},
  editor = {Sandars, Nancy K.},
  date = {1977},
  series = {Penguin Classics},
  edition = {Rev. ed. inc. new material},
  publisher = {{Penguin Books}},
  location = {{Harmondsworth, Middlesex, Engl}},
  isbn = {978-0-14-044100-0},
  langid = {english},
  language = {eng},
  pagetotal = {127}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber,hyperref=true,alldates=comp,url=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{DummyBibliography.bib}

\usepackage{ebgaramond} % Use the EBGaramond font by default
\usepackage{microtype} % Improve justification

\usepackage{lipsum}

\signature{James Adams} % Your name for the signature at the bottom

\address{1001 Main Street \\ Anywhere, AZ 99999} % Your address and phone number

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{John Doe \\ 100 Broadway \\ Somewhere, AZ 11111} % Name/title of the addressee

\opening{John,}
\vspace{\parskip}

\lipsum [1]

As an anonymous author wrote long ago:
\blockquote[\cite{sandarsEpicGilgamesh1977}]
    {
    \lipsum[2]
    }

\lipsum[3]

\vspace{2\parskip} % Extra whitespace for aesthetics
\closing{Sincerely,}
\vspace{2\parskip} % Extra whitespace for aesthetics

\end{letter}

\clearpage
\printbibliography[title = References]

\end{document}
```

I believe that the first time I did this in a letter, I did not receive the error, but I have received it consistently for the last few weeks (I use Kile on ArchLinux, so TeXLive is frequently updated on my system). Strangely, although both PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX end with exit code 1, they also produce a PDF containing a properly formatted letter with the expected bibliography, so this is more of a nuisance than a problem.

Comment: If you want real APA style you should shorten `\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber,hyperref=true,alldates=comp,url=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}` to just `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}`. In any case `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}` hasn't been required for several years now. `sortcites=true,` is preset by `style=apa,`. `sorting=nyt,` actually selects a not fully APA-compliant sorting scheme instead of `style=apa`'s default APA complaint one.

Comment: `hyperref=true,` is usually not more useful than the default `hyperref=auto,`. The only difference between the two is that `hyperref=true,` will warn you if you don't load `\usepackage{hyperref}`. Both option settings will produce links if and only if `\usepackage{hyperref}` is loaded.

Comment: Thank you, moewe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal non-working example for your problem would be

```
\documentclass{letter}
\begin{document}
\section{References}
\end{document}
```

You can avoid the problem by using `\printbibliography[heading=none]`. This will make sure that biblatex won't use a `\section` for the heading:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{knuth:ct}

\textbf{\Large References}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Sam Carter.

Comment: @GaryScottMartin You're welcome!